# How to end only a single task using taskkill?

Tags: cmd, taskkill

I have a `.bat` file that end another `.bat` file using `taskkill` but it ends up killing itself and the other `.bat` file.
So how do I make sure it kills only the oldest `.bat` file?

> Because the 2nd bat file runs after the first

I can't use PID because the PID changes with each run!

`taskkill /im cmd.exe`

This kills all the cmd procceses including itself! I need it to kill only 1 of the processes. (that's the older 1)

Comment: You will of course need to post that actual code in order for us to debug

Comment: The first bat file runs a vbs file not an exe though. But it does  run forever!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this problem before and the way I solved it is:

Have the first script (the file you want to close) looking to see if a temporary file has been made, and if it has, delete the file the close.

```
:loop

if EXIST %TEMP%\close.tmp (
del %TEMP%\close.tmp
exit
)

other code

goto :loop
```

And in the second script (the one closing the first script) just make it create the temporary file.

```
echo do you want to close SCRIPT1?
choice
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 echo.>%TEMP%\close.tmp
```

And if you want to, you can make it so the first script runs more commands before it closes.